# Defining thresholds using pd.cut

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create new labels based on element's value:

```
Number
ewrvdxc12
erw43
cvxe64
fsdf12
eww
fdsvcxc
64
76
2
fds4
7
vcx21
```

I'm splitting in two buckets assigning 1 if the string contains tot number >= threshold, 0 if it contains < or no numbers. I set the threshold equal to 2
E.g.:

```
vcx21 contains 2 numbers so I would assign 1
7 contains 1 number so I would assign 0
fdsvcxc contains no number so I would assign 0
...
```

I did this

```
df['NUM'] = pd.cut(df['Number'], bins=[0,2,100000], labels=['<2','>=2'])
```

but I saw that if strings do not have numbers, it leaves '' (empty).
Can you tell me how to assign 0 to those strings with no numbers in them?

Expected

```
Number              NUM
    ewrvdxc12       >=2
    erw43           >=2
    cvxe64          >=2
    fsdf12          >=2
    eww             <2
    fdsvcxc         <2
    64              >=2
    76              >=2
    2               <2
    fds4            <2 
    7               <2
    vcx21           >=2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should break this problem up into 2 steps

1. Count the number of digits in each string
2. bin those numbers depending on their value

```
# Count the numbers of digits in each string of the "Number" Series
digit_count = df["Number"].str.count("\d")

# Bin numbers & assign back to dataframe
df["Num"] = pd.cut(digit_count, bins=[0, 2, np.inf], right=False, labels=["<2", ">=2"])

print(df)
       Number  Num
0   ewrvdxc12  >=2
1       erw43  >=2
2      cvxe64  >=2
3      fsdf12  >=2
4         eww   <2
5     fdsvcxc   <2
6          64  >=2
7          76  >=2
8           2   <2
9        fds4   <2
10          7   <2
11      vcx21  >=2
```